# Initialize class bean from external JAR - constructor issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javabeans

I'm importing a JAR from an external service. this is the **service class** code:

```
private final PermissionsRepository permissionsRepository;
@Autowired
public PermissionsServiceImpl(PermissionsRepository permissionsRepository) {
    this.permissionsRepository = permissionsRepository;
}
public Collection<Permission> findAll() {
        System.out.println("inside get all permissions");
        return permissionsRepository.findAll();
}
```

while the repository is a regular JPA interface

```
public interface PermissionsRepository extends JpaRepository<Permission, PermissionTable> {}
```

I'm trying to use the "findAll" method in other program I have so I've created a JAR from the above project, imported it and I'm having difficulty to initialize the service bean because I cannot pass the repository as an argument. what's the best way to do so?

This is what I currently have in my BeanConfig class (inside the **other project** which imported the JAR):

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {PermissionsRepository.class})
public class BeansConfig {
// need to create permissionRepository 
   @Bean
    public PermissionsService permissionsService() {
        return new PermissionsServiceImpl(???);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to annotate your repository as a repository and scan it accordingly. EntityScan scans for entities, nor for repositories.

Comment: I don't think it will solve my issue because what I need to do is to figure out how to create a repository instance (of a JPA interface) on the importing project. Once  i'll be able to do that everything should work.

Comment: The whole thing about spring boot data jpa repositories is that they are automatically instantiated by Spring Boot based on their annotation and can be obtained via @Autowired. Please read about about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and take a look at the spring data docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The needed changes are inside the **service** class inside the imported project.

```
@Service
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.internal.myapp"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.demo.internal.myapp.permissions")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.demo.internal.myapp" })
public class PermissionsServiceImpl implements PermissionsService {

    private PermissionsRepository permissionsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PermissionsServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPermissionsService(PermissionsRepository permissionsRepository) {
        this.permissionsRepository = permissionsRepository;
    }

    public Collection<Permission> findAll() {
        System.out.println("inside get all permissions");
        return permissionsRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Basically you need to tell spring where to look for entities- model objects, repositories and more. so i've added 3 annotations:
EntityScan, EnableJpaRepositories and ComponentScan to do just that.

Also did a constructor dependency injection for the repository variable.